# Generic text only printer on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, printer

How do I add Generic / Text Only printer on a Windows Server 2008?

Or is there a way to create a dummy printer on a Windows Server 2008 that flushes everything sent to it to nul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to right click "add printer", and "run as administrator". Don't just doubleclick "add printer" because the option "add local printer" will not be visible (unless you are logging in as administrator already).